# Saving information about a user for analytics in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, flurry

I have two themes for my Android application.
I want to know how many users are using each theme.

I'm using Flurry for analytics, but can't find way to save sate about each user (Flurry is an event driven service, which isn't what I want).

It sounds like a common thing that analytics service should support.
Is there a way to do so with Flurry? or Google Analytics?
If not, what is the best tool for this kind of analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to generate an event with a suitable parameter for the information you want to gather.  I do this global state with an event in my main activity entry point.

The data will be per that event rather than per user but so long as the users of one theme don't have distincly different usage pattent to another then the stats should be valid.